# Как объеденить строки по первому столбцу MySql

Tags: mysql

Буду очень рад помощи.
Сложность в том что и так выборка касается 4 таблиц, плюс сортировка. Результтат запроса на картинке.
Есть запрос sql, который выводит информацию по одному ключу, но для разных поисковиков в 2 строки. Как их объединить?

```
SELECT
  words.zapros, '(', seotimemysitecategory.rang, seomysitecategory.YandexGoogle, ')' 
FROM words, seotimemysitecategory, seomysitecategory, mycategory 
WHERE
  words.idWords = seomysitecategory.idWords AND
  seomysitecategory.idSeomysitecategory = seotimemysitecategory.idSeomysitecategory AND
  mycategory.idMycategory = seomysitecategory.idMycategory AND
  mycategory = 'https://bth.by/catalog/kitchen-shelving/' 
ORDER BY words.zapros
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать технику PIVOT:

```
   select 
        word, 
        min(case when engine = 'Y' then rang else null end) as Y_rang,
        min(case when engine = 'G' then rang else null end) as G_rang
    from words
    group by word;
```

[MySQL pivot online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/00650ddcb148fc673e264422f182615f/)

Comment: Если не сложно, напишите весь запрос, так как я нуб и не понимаю как использовать не только технику пилот, но элементарных основ. Тот запрос что я написал, я потратил 3 часа времени)))

Comment: @Александр, Опубликуйте структуру таблиц и тестовые данные на https://SQLize.online и опубликуйте ссылку

Comment: Я правильно понял? https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/9cf1b9439f3dd1f1ff02a3879dfc12b1/